# Problema ao gravar campo decimal mysql

Tags: php, mysql, decimal

Do nada começou um problema que não encontrei explicação. Segue meu código, explanando o problema.

Aqui recebo os dados:

```
$venda = $_POST['f_venda']; //Sim
$preco_venda = $_POST['f_preco_venda']; //360000
$imovel = $_POST['f_imovel']; //2564

$real = 'R$ ' . number_format($preco_venda, 2, ',', '.'); // R$360.000,00
```

Aqui gravo os dados na tabela e ocorre o problema. O campo preco_venda deveria ser atualizado para 360000, porém está gravando o numeral 1, e o campo venda deveria ser alterado para Sim, porém se mantém em Não:

```
$sql_preco_venda = "UPDATE imoveis SET preco = '$preco_venda' AND venda = '$venda' WHERE controle LIKE '$imovel'";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql_preco_venda);
```

Nestes dois INSERTS os campos são gravados corretamente, ou seja, $venda grava Sim e $real grava R$360.000,00:

```
$sql_rastros = "INSERT INTO rastros VALUES ('0', '$user_nome', now(), now(), 'alterou opção ($venda) e preço de venda do imóvel código $cod_int para $real')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql_rastros);

$sql_historia = "INSERT INTO historia VALUES ('0', '$user_nome', now(), '$imovel', 'Opção ($venda) e preço de venda alterado para $real')";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql_historia);
```

Realmente já tentei de tudo e não detectei o erro. Agradeço sua ajuda.

Comment: Experimente remover o AND e adicionar apenas uma VIRGULA (,) no seu UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certamente está ocorrendo um erro de sintaxe no seu seu UPDATE.

Em vez de você usar `AND`, você deve usar uma virgula (`,`) para definir o valor do `preco` e da `venda`. O `AND` deve ser usado para este caso, somente para `WHERE`, adicionando uma ou mais condições para a atualização.

Como está:

```
$sql_preco_venda = "UPDATE imoveis SET preco = '$preco_venda' AND venda = '$venda' WHERE controle LIKE '$imovel'";
```

Como deve ser de fato:

```
$sql_preco_venda = "UPDATE imoveis SET preco = '$preco_venda', venda = '$venda' WHERE controle LIKE '$imovel'";
```

Comment: KKK. Passei 8 horas tentando consertar uma coisa básica... acho que é o stress! Era isso mesmo, MUITO OBRIGADO.

Comment: @WagnerEstilloWeb normal, acontece com as melhores famílidas. =D Caso tenha ajudado, se quiser, pode validar a resposta. Abraços. Boa sorte.

Comment: Pronto, validei.